# User frequently log out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a web application built in ASP.NET MVC 4. that is hosted on shared hosting server. On that servers for each package(domain) there is limitation of 100 MB memory for the application pools, if it goes above 100 MB, causing the application pool to restart and session is lost having all your visitors logged out.

I have two options to sort it out :

1. SessionState = StateServer
2. Machine Key (From http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

I have tried first with no luck(still user logout in two or three requests).
i have tried second but my problem is that i have 2000-3000 existing user if i put the 
the machine key into my web.config file its prevents the existing user to login with there current password.

i am using Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers for authentication

any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Machine key just changes the way how form cookies are encrypted; so once you change the machine key, they're just logged out (but they can log in using their old password). Also there is a difference between authentication and session state - "log out" means user lose his authentication cookie/ his cookie expire - restarting app pool doesn't log off users. You're probably talking about session state.

Comment: That is not much memory for an app pool that has that many users.  I would either try and increase it or look for a way to minimize the amount of memory your site uses.